# How to fetch data just one time from firebase and don't listen to any data change

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase and recently started working on this. Every tutorial I saw, is about how to listen to data change in cloud firestore. What if I want to fetch teh data just once and don't wanna set anyy listener on them. Example scenario is, just fetching the data user last login time or profile data of any user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has a dedicated section about [getting data a single time for a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).  Just use the `get()` method on the query you build:

```java
db.collection("cities")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Or, [for a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document):

```java
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```